# My audio does not work

Tags: audio

My PC is Lenovo M6900.Audio Card 82801G(ICH7 Family).And I have set 2 OS on the machine. windows xp (sp2) and linux (openSUSE 10.3).When I'm doing under windows,audio is pretty ok. but when i switched to linux,it's just been mute.Can anybody help?Thanks.

Comment: Please do not post one question multiple times.
- On a side note, consider checking the model number of the onboard sound. You can fetch a list of the PCI devices via 

# lspci

Comment: Duplicate by the same user: http://superuser.com/questions/156077/my-audio-does-not-work

Comment: sorry i will make it right next time

Answer (score 0):

It's not a hardware problem if it works under windows. You most likely don't have an appropriate sound driver installed under Linux. I'd suggest working through the [openSUSE audio troubleshooting guide](http://wiki.opensuse.org/SDB:Audio_troubleshooting).